# Flutter - AndroidManifest.xml corrupted after Flutter Upgrade

Tags: android, xml, flutter, android-manifest

I've just upgraded to Flutter 2 and upgraded an application along with it. I followed all the steps to upgrade the application, but now I can't seem to run the app because my AndroidManifest.xml file seems corrupted.

Here is the xml file (I've also added comments where the errors are appearing).

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.finances_management">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication" <-- Unresolved class 'FlutterApplication' 
        android:label="finances_management"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"> <-- Cannot resolve symbol '@mipmap/ic_launcher'
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity" <-- Unresolved class 'MainActivity' 
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme" <-- Cannot resolve symbol '@style/LaunchTheme'
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" <-- Cannot resolve symbol '@style/NormalTheme' 
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" <-- Cannot resolve symbol '@drawable/launch_background' 
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I've seen elsewhere that people are just completely rebuilding their projects (as in completely generating a new project, stripping business logic from their Flutter 1.x app and copying it across to a Flutter 2.x app). Does anyone know what's happened to my XML file?

Comment: Have you tried flutter clean and rebuilding it again? Have the exact same line you pointed out, but working fine

Comment: Try commenting out this line though `android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"`

Comment: Turns out my project had got into a state after the upgrade. I just cleaned the project and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to downgrade the Flutter . after that update AndroidManifest file